# Biological replicates

Tags: microbiology, biostatistics

We are currently doing an screening where supernatans from a bacteria genus are tested againts a pathogenic bacteria cell culture in a 96-well plate where OD is measured each 2 hours.

Each supernatant from a strain has 3  replicates  and the control phatogenic bacteria cell culture has about 11 replicates inside the plate.

Once each experiment is finished cell growth curves are modelated and 3 growth parameters are determined (mu, lambda and max absorbance) from each supernatant tested and from the control. Then a Mann-withney U test is performed for each growth parameter from each strain againts corresponding control parameter to check if there's some kind of possible inhibition.

The strains which has some inhibition efect againts this pathogenic bacteria will be tested again in further experiments to confirm the possible positive.

I  have a doubt about if performing statistical test to compare supernatants from each plate againts its corresponding control is correct considering that the possible candidates will be again tested in further experiments to confirm its inhibition. Since there's loads of strains to test, repeating each single experiment more than 3 times would take too long.

What it is your oipinion? Is it correct to do statistics for single plate (technical replicates) to gather possible positive for a later confirmation (biological replicates)?

Thank you

Are biological replicates strictly needed in this case?

Comment: You might have better luck with this question on https://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: These might be interesting to you: http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v492/n7428/full/492180a.html https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3321166/